# String: replace last ".something" in a string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have some string and I would like to replace the last .something with a new string. As example:

```
string replace = ".new";
blabla.test.bla.text.jpeg => blabla.test.bla.text.new
testfile_this.00001...csv => testfile_this.00001...new
```

So it doesn't matter how many `.....` there are, I'd like to change only the last one and the string what after the last `.` is coming.

I saw in C# there is **Path.ChangeExtension** but its only working in a combination with a **File** - Is there no way to use this with a string only? Do I really need regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string replace = ".new";
string p = "blabla.test.bla.text.jpeg";
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p) + replace);
```

**Output:**

```
blabla.test.bla.text.new
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `string.LastIndexOf('.');`

```
string replace = ".new"; 
string test = "blabla.test.bla.text.jpeg";
int pos = test.LastIndexOf('.');
if(pos >= 0)
    string newString = test.Substring(0, pos-1) + replace;
```

of course some checking is required to be sure that LastIndexOf finds the final point.

However, seeing the other answers, let me say that, while Path.ChangeExtension works, it doesn't feel right **to me** to use a method from a operating system dependent file handling class to manipulate a string. (Of course, if this string is really a filename, then my objection is invalid)

Answer (score 4):

`ChangeExtension` should work as advertised;

```
string replace = ".new";
string file = "testfile_this.00001...csv";

file = Path.ChangeExtension(file, replace);

>> testfile_this.00001...new
```

Comment: Huh, ChangeExtension for string only. Ok... didnt know ^^ Looks nice

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "blabla.test.bla.text.jpeg";
s = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(".")) + replace;
```

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need regular expressions for this. Just .LastIndexOf and .Substring will suffice.

```
string replace = ".new";
string input = "blabla.bla.test.jpg";

string output = input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf('.')) + replace;
// output = "blabla.bla.test.new"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this function.

```
public string ReplaceStirng(string originalSting, string replacedString)
{
    try
    {
        List<string> subString = originalSting.Split('.').ToList();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < subString.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(subString[i]);
        }
        stringBuilder.Append(replacedString);
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (log.IsErrorEnabled)
            log.Error("[" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "] " + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.FullName + " :: " + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name + " :: ", ex);
            throw;
    }
}
```